# Logical error in display/math not displaying initial result

Tags: c#, math, return, return-value

I have a population estimator program for school, the results do not display the first set of results. Here is the code.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double startingPop;
    double increasePer;
    double numDays;

    const int INTERVAL = 1;

    if (double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out startingPop))
    {
        if (double.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out increasePer))
        {
            if (double.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out numDays))
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= numDays; i += INTERVAL)
                {
                    startingPop = (startingPop * (increasePer / 100) + startingPop);
                    Results.Items.Add("After " + i + " days, the amount of organisms is " + startingPop);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}

private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = "";
    textBox2.Text = "";
    textBox3.Text = "";
    Results.Items.Clear();
}
```

I want it to show day 1 2 organisms, instead it shows the first calculation with the increase percentage i.e (day 1 2.6). I know this is probably super obvious so I apologize. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: What are the values of the textboxes?

Comment: Looks like all you need to do is to just swap the two lines inside the `for` loop. That being said, are you sure that this is a logical error? In other words, are you sure that _"**After** 1 day"_, the population should _still_ be the same as the starting population?

Comment: No, I need it to show the starting pop on day 1, then show the pop for the days after after the increase is applied. The startingPop variable is also the estimated population.

It should show like this
Day 1 2 organisms
Day 2 2.6 organisms
day 3 3.38 ect, it shows up as Day 1 2.6 currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, your code should look something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double startingPop;
    double increasePer;
    double numDays;

    const int INTERVAL = 1;

    if (double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out startingPop) &&
        double.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out increasePer) &&
        double.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out numDays))
    {
        Results.Items.Add("On the first day, the amount of organisms is " + startingPop);

        for (int i = 1; i <= numDays; i += INTERVAL)
        {
            startingPop = (startingPop * (increasePer / 100) + startingPop);
            Results.Items.Add("After " + i + " day(s), the amount of organisms is " + startingPop);
        }
    }
}
```

The changes I made to the code:

- Combine the three `if` statements into one using the [`&&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-and-operator-) operator.
- Print the population value *before increasing it* so that the next displayed value (which reads *"after 1 day"*) will be the next incremented value.
- To make your result items grammatically correct, you may the second line inside the loop with something like:

  ```
  string s = (i > 1 ? "s" : string.Empty);
  Results.Items.Add($"After {i} day{s}, the amount of organisms is {startingPop}.");
  ```

Now, assuming the values in `textBox1`, `textBox2`, `textBox3` are 2, 30, and 5, the displayed result would be something like this:

[image: Result]